# Где лучше хранить временные ключи?

Tags: php, сессия, memcached

Работаю с API. При авторизации приходит временный токен, который действует один час. Скажите, пожалуйста, где его лучше хранить этот токен и время его действия?. В базе там, в кэше, или в сессии.

Comment: А это смотря как он использоваться будет. Как он соотносится с пользователями сайта, т.е. может ли использоваться совместно несколькими пользователями

Comment: @mike К пользователя сайта он по сути никак не относиться. Он нужен для сбора информации об объявлениях ( успешно выгружено, с ошибками и пр), это информация записывается в базу. А затем отдается юзеру в виде таблицы. Просто этот апи используют несколько скриптов. И чтобы каждые не авторизовавался, хотел сделать где-то хранилище временого токена

Comment: Ответ на вопрос лежит в плоскости требований, а именнно: должны ли токены оставаться действительными при перезагрузке сервера? допускается ли произвольное протухание токена (это возможно если использется кеш, там значения могут стираться, когда памяти не хватает)? должен ли токен оставаться действительным, когда закрывается сессия?

Comment: @VechoKrainii Раз к пользователям не относится, значит исключили сессию. А в БД или каком нибудь кеше, при небольшом количестве обращений разницы не имеет, кладите куда удобнее.